# Class properties not setting in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am storing values in SimpleClass from the ViewController and i am getting in Secondview class. But i am unable to get the values from the  SimpleClass in SecondClass. Help me 
Thanks

[Demo Project](https://www.facebook.com/download/1460766810889139/HttpHelper.zip)

Comment: Some sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: Need permission to open the code on Google Drive.

Comment: Better upload to GitHub or post code here

Comment: Here is my demo :https://www.facebook.com/download/1460766810889139/HttpHelper.zip

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because in `SecondClass` you are creating a new instance of `SimpleClass`.

What you really want to do is to pass the `SimpleClass` instance from `ViewController` to `SecondClass`.

One way to do this is using the `prepareForSegue` method in 'ViewController`

on `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var simObject:SimpleClass?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "First Class";

        simObject = SimpleClass()
        simObject!.userName = "damu";
        simObject!.userPassword = "123";
        simObject!.address = "344r";

        print(simObject!.address)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // pass the simObject to secondClass
        if let secondClass = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondClass {
            secondClass.simpleClass = simObject
        }
    }

}
```

On `SeconClass.swift`

```
import UIKit

class SecondClass: UIViewController {

    var simpleClass:SimpleClass?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Second Class";

        if let passedSimpleClass = self.simpleClass {
            println(passedSimpleClass.address)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values from the ViewController to your SecondView you have to implement

> override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender:
>   AnyObject?)

You're getting the right value for temp.username which is nil displayed in log when you go to the Secondview. This is because you're creating a new instance of SimpleClass who's variables are initialised to nil.